como poder hacer funcionar las consultas multitablas desde laravel
Tengo esta función la cual la estoy consumiendo desde una API, pero hago pruebas en postman y me lanza un error
 public function obtenerVideosAceptados()
{
    $videos = DB::table('video')
        ->select('video.url', 'video.miniatura', 'video.nombre', 'video.descripcion', 'video.fk_usuario', 'canal.nombre_canal', 'canal.imagen')
        ->join('canal', 'canal.fk_usuario', '=', 'video.fk_usuario')
        ->where('video.estado', '0')
        ->get();

        return VideoResource::collection($videos);
}

Este es el error que me da postman, el cual no se a que se deba, apenas empiezo a trabajar con laravel:
"SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 
 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: 
 \"videosAceptados\"\nCONTEXT:  
 unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...' (Connection: pgsql, 
 SQL: select * from \"video\" where \"pk_video\" = 
 videosAceptados limit 1)",


Podrias adjuntar la estructura de las tablas? por que parece que es un error de tipos de dato de los campos.
